# Javascript regex to find a string and extract it from whole string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I have a Javascript array of string that contains urls like:

```
http://www.example.com.tr/?first=DSPN47ZTE1BGMR&second=NECEFT8RYD
http://www.example.com.tr/?first=RTR22414242144&second=YUUSADASFF
http://www.example.com.tr/?first=KOSDFASEWQESAS&second=VERERQWWFA
http://www.example.com.tr/?first=POLUJYUSD41234&second=13F241DASD
http://www.example.com.tr/?first=54SADFD14242RD&second=TYY42412DD
```

I want to extract "first" query parameter values from these url.

I mean i need values DSPN47ZTE1BGMR, RTR22414242144, KOSDFASEWQESAS, POLUJYUSD41234, 54SADFD14242RD

Because i am not good using regex, i couldnt find a way to extract these values from the array. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters) and [How to obtain the query string from the current URL with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870512) and [get querystring using javascript and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449921)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using regex, why not just create a URL object out of the string and extract the parameters natively?

```
let url = new URL("http://www.example.com.tr/?first=54SADFD14242RD&second=TYY42412DD");
console.log(url.searchParams.get("first")); // -> "54SADFD14242RD"
```

If you don't know the name of the first parameter, you can still manually search the query string using the URL constructor.

```
let url = new URL("http://www.example.com.tr/?first=54SADFD14242RD&second=TYY42412DD");
console.log(url.search.match(/\?([^&$]+)/)[1]); // -> "54SADFD14242RD"
```

The index of the search represents the parameter's position (with index zero being the whole matched string). Note that `.match` returns `null` for no matches, so the code above would throw an error if there's no parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to use regex? Would something like the following work:

```
var x = 'http://www.example.com.tr/?first=DSPN47ZTE1BGMR&second=NECEFT8RYD';
x.split('?first=')[1].split('&second')[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
first=([^&]*)
```

Capture the contents of Group 1

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E2DZ1j/1/)**

**[Code](https://regex101.com/r/E2DZ1j/1/codegen?language=javascript)**

**Explanation:**

- `first=` - matches `first=`
- `([^&]*)` - matches 0+ occurences of any character that is not a `&` and stores it in Group 1

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
(?<=\?first=)[^&]+?
```

- `(?<=\?first=)` - positive look behind to match `?first=`
- `[^&]+?`  - Matches any character up to `&` (lazy mode)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YvYPTq/1/)

Without positive look behind you do like this

```js
let str = `http://www.example.com.tr/?first=DSPN47ZTE1BGMR&second=NECEFT8RYD
http://www.example.com.tr/?first=RTR22414242144&second=YUUSADASFF
http://www.example.com.tr/?first=KOSDFASEWQESAS&second=VERERQWWFA
http://www.example.com.tr/?first=POLUJYUSD41234&second=13F241DASD
http://www.example.com.tr/?first=54SADFD14242RD&second=TYY42412DD`

let op = str.match(/\?first=([^&]+)/g).map(e=> e.split('=')[1])

console.log(op)
```